# Rename file names in directory to creation timestamp with second precision

Tags: terminal, automator, filesystem, file, macos

Is there an easy way to do this for files in a particular directory - to have their names be renamed to the file timestamp, with seconds level precision

Clarification:

For example, suppose a (Mac 10.14.15) directory has the following files, where the notation below shows original file name and file creation time. (But, to be clear, we are working from the Mac file directory, and not from the luxury of just parsing thru a text file.) The filenames are uuid 36 character names:

```
35eafb32-8005-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64.png 09:35:01
419f0eb4-8005-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64.png 09:35:11
43249984-8005-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64.png 21:02:03
```

Suppose I want to rename the files based on (original creation) timestamp, but the filename of course has to be in an acceptable format:

```
prepend-09_35_01.png
prepend-09_35_11.png
prepend-21_02_03.png
```

(In the actual case, the directory has 2000+ files. If it matters, they are transported from an iPhone X app I made - through iTunes file sharing. The file creation date and time shows up correctly on Mac when transferred.)

Comment: Are all 2000+ files in the same directory? Are there any subdirectories in the directory that contains the 2000+ files? Is `prepend` in `prepend-09_35_01.png` the original filename? I also said, "Also, as you have the automator tag, show us your workflow too.", yet you did not comment nor have you said what type of solution you'd prefer, `bash` script to use in Terminal only or an Automator workflow, etc.  It's really a shame you just couldn't' be explicit and specific!

Comment: tbh i haven't been able to get anything to work in automator for this. maybe terminal batch scripts might be an easier approach? and yes, all files in a directory.

Comment: I posted an answer (at this point 2 hours ago), are you saying it didn't work for you?

Comment: yes thanks for your thorough answer! learned a lot!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all the files are in the same *directory*, then in **Terminal**, changed directory, e.g.
 `cd /path/to/directory` and then use the following *compound command*:

```
for f in *.*; do echo mv -n "$f" "${f%.*}-$(stat -f'%SB' -t "%H_%M_%S" "$f").${f##*.}"; done
```

Note: There is an intensional `echo` *command* that is there for you to test with, and it will only print out the `mv` *command* for you to see that it's the outcome you wish. You can then run it again removing just `echo` from the *compound command* to actually rename the files as desired via the `mv` *command*.

## Example:

```
$ touch 35eafb32-8005-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64.png 419f0eb4-8005-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64.png 43249984-8005-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64.png
$
$ ls -1
35eafb32-8005-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64.png
419f0eb4-8005-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64.png
43249984-8005-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64.png
$
$ for f in *.*; do echo mv -n "$f" "${f%.*}-$(stat -f'%SB' -t "%H_%M_%S" "$f").${f##*.}"; done
mv -n 35eafb32-8005-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64.png 35eafb32-8005-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64-19_56_35.png
mv -n 419f0eb4-8005-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64.png 419f0eb4-8005-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64-19_56_35.png
mv -n 43249984-8005-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64.png 43249984-8005-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64-19_56_35.png
$
$ for f in *.*; do mv -n "$f" "${f%.*}-$(stat -f'%SB' -t "%H_%M_%S" "$f").${f##*.}"; done
$
$ ls -1
35eafb32-8005-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64-19_56_35.png
419f0eb4-8005-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64-19_56_35.png
43249984-8005-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64-19_56_35.png
$
```

## Understanding the `bash` *compound command*:

- `for f in *.*; do ...; done`    For every *file* in the *current dir* do the following *command(s)* to them.
- `echo`    Print what follows. (Must be removed for the `mv` *command* to actually work.)
- `mv -n source target`    Move files, do not overwrite an existing file, *filename*, *new filename*.

  - `"$f"`    The *source filename*.
  - `"${f%.*}-$(stat -f'%SB' -t "%H_%M_%S" "$f").${f##*.}"`    The *target filename*.
  - `${f%.*}`    *Name* portion of the *filename* without the *extension*. See **Parameter Expansion** in the `bash` *man page*.
  - `-`    The HYPHEN-MINUS character.
  - `$(...)`    **Command Substitution**, allows the *output* of a *command* to replace the *command name*.
  - `stat -f'%SB' -t "%H_%M_%S" "$f"`
  - `stat`    Display file status. See its *man page* for more details.
  - `-f'%SB'`    −f *format*    Display information using the specified format. See the FORMATS section for a description of valid formats. In this case `%SB` represents *string output* of the *birth time* of the *inode*. (The *time* the *file* was created.)
  - `-t "%H_%M_%S"`    −t *timefmt*    Display timestamps using the specified format. This format is passed directly to strftime(3). In this case it represents the *hour*, a LOW LINE character (AKA underscore), the *minute*, a LOW LINE character, the *second*.
  - `%H`    Is replaced by the *hour* as a decimal number (00-23).
  - `%M`    Is replaced by the *minute* as a decimal number (00-59).
  - `%S`    Is replaced by the *second* as a decimal number (00-60).
  - `"$f"`    The *source filename*.
  - `.`    The FULL STOP character. (AKA dot or period.)
  - `${f##*.}`    The *extension* portion of the *filename*. See **Parameter Expansion** in the `bash` *man page*.

<sup>Note that the upper case character names are that which show in Character Viewer on a US English install of macOS.</sup>

Comment: very thorough explanation. `for f in *.*; do mv -n "$f" "prepend-$(stat -f'%SB' -t "%H_%M_%S" "$f").${f##*.}"; done` worked! thanks !